# Refresh Content of different Component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm asking myself how to reload the content of a different Component in Angular using NGFaces. Background is the following: after a successful post request i would like to reload the view to show the most recent data retrieved from a get request.
The Insert Page/Component is in a different Class.

```
public create(name, description, archived, selectedParents): void {
http.post.subscribe(() => {
  this.messageService.success('Worked');
//here the other component should call the get method and refresh the page afterwards
}, () => {
  this.messageService.error('Error');
});;
}
```

the other component has the following method:

```
 http.get.subscribe(data => {
     this.data = data;
    });
```

I am using PrimeNG so I can't use $scope variables.

http Methods are simplified in this code snippets.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: angular or angularjs? Please tag accordingly :)

Comment: @AJT_82 done :)

Comment: And please check your other tags to. Read the infp about them. One is plain wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular's `Output` decorator like this:

```
import { EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Output() updateView = new EventEmitter();

public create(name, description, archived, selectedParents): void {
http.post.subscribe(() => {
  this.messageService.success('Worked');
  //here the other component should call the get method and refresh the page afterwards
  this.updateView.emit();
}, () => {
  this.messageService.error('Error');
});;
}
```

finally in your "other component" template, you would have this:

```
<app-insert-page (updateView)="otherComponentGetMethod()"></app-insert-page>
```

More info [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event).

Comment: This works very good! Thanks. My Problem I still have is that i have my API calls all in a different File. The calls in the OtherComponentGetMethod are done until it comes to something like this.model.getall().subscribe... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Feel free to create a new question. You might be looking for info on Services.